# Chrome not destroying native session on window close

Tags: php, google-chrome, session, cookies

I have encountered a troubling issue: chrome is not destroying native sessions when closing tabs or the entire chrome browser. This happens if the "continue where you left" option is selected in Chrome's settings. I would like to find a way to make sure Chrome is destroying the session (deleting the session cookie) regardless of how users configure their individual Chrome settings.

Here is a sample code I am using to test the existence of a session:

```
<?php 
    session_start(); 
    if ( isset($_SESSION['check'])) echo 'An active session was found.';
    else
    {
        $_SESSION['check'] = TRUE;
        echo 'An inactive session was found and activated.';
    }
?>
```

To test the session-destroying functionality of the browser I open this code in a browser, then close the browser and reopen it. The output after this process is as follows:

Firefox: An inactive session was found and activated.
Explorer: An inactive session was found and activated.
Chrome: An active session was found.

How can I make sure the session is properly destroyed when the tab or browser are closed?

Answer (score 1):

From how I interpret the [RFC 6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265) browsers **are not required** to drop so called "session cookies" (those that don't have expiration date set) on their process shutdown.

So it makes sense to not rely on a particular implementation but on specification.

In your case it means: it's not possible to do what you want; you need to rethink your solution.